# get pixel value of an uint8 Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

In some other threads I read that a uint8 element can be accessed by

```
value = myMat.at<uint8_t>(Point(x,y));
```

My system doesn't recognize uint8_t as an datatype.
Do I have to include something or do I have to use another datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint8_t` is defined inside `cstdint`. So, you need to use `#include <cstdint>`